# Can I get the spellchecker in MS Word to remember my grammar decisions?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, spell-check, grammar

Sometimes Word will make a incorrect grammar suggestion which I can just ignore.

However every time I go to spellcheck it again, it will keep making that suggestion. Is there any way I can get it to remember not to make that particular suggestion for that phrase in that document.

Comment: I don't have Word anywhere here, but if memory serves there's some way to mark a section as no-language so that the grammar check (and the spell check :( ) will not fire.

Comment: I don't find a way to edit the bounty text, so I'll add it here: If I ignore once, the spell checker will mark it again if I do changes in the paragraph. This is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent Word from spell-checking just one word in the document,
one could apply a style that doesn't spell-check.
This will require creating a new style, if you don't wish to destroy an existing one.

The steps to follow are :

1. Apply a style to the terms you want skipped. You can use an existing
   style or create a custom style but the style you apply to the terms
   you want skipped must be different from the other styles used
   throughout the document.
2. Click the Home tab and click the Styles group's dialog launcher.
3. In the Styles task pane, select the style you want skipped.
4. From the style's dropdown menu, choose `Modify`.
5. In the resulting dialog box, choose `Language` from the Format dropdown.
6. Check the `Do Not Check Spelling Or Grammar` option.
7. Click OK twice and close the Styles task pane.

[image]

For more information see :
[Skipping text in Word while spell checking a document](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/skipping-text-in-word-while-spell-checking-a-document/).

Comment: You don’t need to use a style for this. You can just set it as a property of the text, same as you can set text to bold, italic, underlined, colored, etc…, without using a style.

Comment: @Scott: Where is that done?

Comment: Go to the “Review” tab, “Language” panel, “Language” button -> “Set Proofing Language…”.

Comment: @Scott: You are right, and this is much simpler than my answer. You should put it in an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1):

For spelling errors, right click on the offending word and click "Add to Dictionary".  For offending grammar, right click in the grammar error and click "Ignore Rule".  Any use of these words and phrases will no longer be flagged in the document.

Comment: You actually need an "Ignore rule *in this case only* " option ;)

Comment: @ChrisF : Yes that's my problem exactly