# Getting Microsoft Word Grammar Check to treat certain words as proper nouns

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the spellchecker in MS Word to remember my grammar decisions](https://superuser.com/questions/135518/can-i-get-the-spellchecker-in-ms-word-to-remember-my-grammar-decisions)

I have a word document which frequently refers to a computer system called "I/90". When I run a grammar check it often wants to change this to "me/90" :-). It also wants to treat "I/90" as a plural because it thinks there are ninety of them. I've tried adding I/90 to the Custom dictionary to no avail. Is there anything else I can do?

I'm using Word 2003.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate (also asked by you) of [Can I get the spellchecker in MS Word to remember my grammar decisions](http://superuser.com/questions/135518/can-i-get-the-spellchecker-in-ms-word-to-remember-my-grammar-decisions).  Seems like the same basic question to me anyway "How can I get the Grammar Checker to remember my choices for specific phrases", others may not agree. :)  PS: Please consider accepting some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only way to get around this is to disable "Misused Words" checking in the Grammar Settings. Although then you're potentially partially defeating the purpose of the grammar checker.  Unfortunately as of now, Microsoft Office Grammar checking does not take into account the custom dictionary like the spell checker component does.

[image: Grammar Settings]

Another option is to create a Microsoft Word Template with that rule ignored, and then always use that template when you write about the "I/90", although my guess is that is doing the same thing as disabling the "Misused Words" rule manually; the only benefit by using the template is that you won't forget to turn it back on when you are writing documents for other purposes.

Comment: I added a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks; it's doing it now for me.  Please hold while I research and I will update my answer.

Comment: Edited my post to show my suggestion / work-around solution. Hope this helps.